# PHP try catch, if exception > stop

Tags: php, try-catch

i'm new with the `try/Catch` option in PHP, so i created this:

```
try {
    $dropbox->Delete($_POST['truncNaam']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<div class="error">Exception: '. $e->getMessage() .'</div>';
}

echo "Success";
```

When an error occurres now, i will see the error but also i will see " SUCCESS ".
I don't want that, i want to see the error when it occurress OR i want to show the SUCCESS if there was no exception.

I just can't figure out how to realize that. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: echo "Success"; should have been inside "try" Right?

Comment: Add a die or exit to your catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
try {

    $dropbox->Delete($_POST['truncNaam']);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<div class="error">Exception: '. $e->getMessage() .'</div>';
    die();

}

echo "Success";
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
$caught = false;

try {

    $dropbox->Delete($_POST['truncNaam']);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<div class="error">Exception: '. $e->getMessage() .'</div>';
    $caught = true;

}

if (!$caught) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: I thought there might be an option in the try/catch, but i assume there is not. Then i take the second option, don't like to use die(). Thank you.